# Exception the exception thrown from Stream.forEach() in ControllerAdvice

Tags: spring-mvc, exception, controller-advice

In my Spring MVC Based application, I have a `ControllerAdvice` defined.

Now, in one of my service classes, I have this `parallelStream` created:

```
rawImportList.parallelStream().forEach(rawImportBatch -> {
    rawImportBatch.parallelStream().forEach(this::importNominationFromRawImport)
});
```

The `importNominationFromRawImport()` method here, by definition, could throw a custom exception that should ideally be handled in the `ControllerAdvice`.

What could be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: The exception if thrown, and is defined in the ControllerAdvice should be caught there...I dont understand your question exactly :)  What is happening now? What is it that you want to happen?

Comment: @SMA This line:
`rawImportBatch.parallelStream().forEach(this::importNominationFromRawImport)`

Complains that the exception needs to be handled. The only option I seem to be having here is to surround it with a try-catch block. That doesn't help since I cannot really propagate this to my API response.

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Your case is the typical (Checked exception in a Lambda expression and how to handle it)

A) Catch and convert to a CustomRunTimeException which you can catch in your ControllerAdvice
B) Change this CheckedException you are throwing from `ImportNomination` to a CustomRunTimeException
C) Look into jooq library which has `Unchecked.consumer()` which throws an UncheckedException

Comment: @SMA Option  `A`  worked for me, thanks!